# Doctrine2 Event Listeners? Subscribers? Dispatching?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've read the documentation several times but I am missing something.. I can't seem to make this work.

Scenario: I have an entity of Tshirts (id,qtyTotals) and an entity of Sizes (tshirt_id, size, qty) and every time a new Size is created,updated or deleted, I need to update the Tshirts.qtyTotals by selecting all the Sizes, adding them up and updating the totals.

I am sure I could do this from my controller in 2 separate steps, but I feel the Events approach is the right one.

I've been reading this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners specially the 2.4 sections.

I was trying to use the annotation: @ORM\EntityListeners({"TshirtListener"}) but the class is found but never execute it....

How do I define the events? how do I dispatch them? What is the difference between a Listener and a Subscriber?

A simple example would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the association type between the Tshirts and Sizes enitites?

Answer (score 3):

You can attach events to an Entity using the Doctrine Event Manager in the module `Module.php` class in the `onBootstrap` function like the following:

```
class Module 
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $application           = $e->getApplication();
        $sm                    = $application->getServiceManager();
        $doctrineEntityManager = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        $doctrineEventManager  = $doctrineEntityManager->getEventManager();
        $doctrineEventManager->addEventListener(
            array(\Doctrine\ORM\Events::prePersist, \Doctrine\ORM\Events::preUpdate),
            new \Application\Listener\MyEntityListener($sm)
        );
    }
}
```

And in the Listener you can do what ever you want like this for example:

```
namespace Application\Listener;

class EntityListener
{
    private $sm;

    public function __construct($sm)
    {
        $this->sm = $sm;
    }

    public function prePersist($eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if (method_exists($entity, 'setTotals')) {
            //Update entity totals
        }
    }

    public function preUpdate($eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if (method_exists($entity, 'setTotals')) {
            //Update entity totals
        }
    }
}
```